# Linux associate USB port to device

Tags: linux, usb, usb-drive

I have an array of micro-SD card readers connected to a single Linux computer (currently I have 14 devices connected through two USB3 hubs)

I need to write a program to monitor insertion/writing/checking of each card.

How to handle a single micro-SD is not a problem.

Problem is to reliably associate a number to each physical and logical device.

I can monitor when `/dev/sdX` appears and react to that, but how can I associate this logical device with the physical device, as listed by `lsusb`?

I need to write a simple GUI with an array of buttons each connected to a *physical device* in a certain *physical position* and maintain association even if/when micro-SD is removed/reinserted and even if the whole card reader is disconnected.

Again: problem is not how to write such a GUI, but how to get information about what is happening on a single HUB slot.

For each slot I need to know:

- If there's a Card reader inserted
- If there's a card in the card reader
- Logical device (`/dev/sdX`) of the inserted card

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242546/64699

Comment: Thanks @stark, That should allow me to map USB device to physical location (fist bullet), but I still need to map USB device (e.g.: `/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5.1.1`) to actual block device (i.e.: `/dev/sdb`) (bullet 3); I can assume there's a micro-SD inserted IFF I can actually make above association (bullet 2). Any further hint?

Comment: Under /sys/block there should be a device path link.  Poke around with ``ls -l`